# Using comma before format spec. in scanf in C?

Tags: c, scanf

I have a function like this:

```c
void getCommands( int commands[][ 2 ] )
{ 
   int i, tempCommand;
   
   printf( "Enter command ( 9 to end input ): " );
   scanf( "%d", &tempCommand );
   
   for ( i = 0; tempCommand != 9 && i < MAX; i++ )
   { 
      commands[ i ][ 0 ] = tempCommand;

      if ( tempCommand == 5 )
         scanf( ",%d", &commands[ i ][ 1 ] );
        
      printf( "Enter command ( 9 to end input ): " );
      scanf( "%d", &tempCommand );
    }

   commands[ i ][ 0 ] = 9;
   
 }
```

My question is what the `",%d"` means in:

```c
    if ( tempCommand == 5 )
        scanf( ",%d", &commands[ i ][ 1 ] );
```

What I'm trying to say is how does that comma before `%d` work?

You can actually see from the code below exactly what I mean (type `5,12` in reponse to the first prompt, for example).

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a,b=0;
    scanf("%d",&a);
    printf("%d %d\n",a,b);
    scanf(",%d",&b);
    printf("%d %d",a,b);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The comma (or any other non-whitespace character not preceded by the `%` format specifier) signals that any such *identical* character in the input stream is 'skipped' (i.e. consumed but not used); if a matching comma is *not* found, the `scanf` call fails.

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf):

> non-whitespace multibyte characters except %: each such character in
> the format string consumes exactly one identical character from the
> input stream, or causes the function to fail if the next character on
> the stream does not compare equal.

So, in your example, when `5,12` is given as input, the first `scanf` call extracts the `5` value (into `a`) then the next call skips the `,` and reads the `12` into `b` (using the `%d` format).

Comment: I Wonder how its automatically give to b 12 EVEN though 12 was in the first scanf

Comment: @Ahmet The first `scanf` call stops reading/consuming the input buffer once it's taken out the `5` (with the `%d` format); the input buffer then still has the remainder of your original input left in it ... and that remainder will be processed by the next call to `scanf`.